# Determine if user still hasn't removed App from his Facebook account

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I've managed to have an user sign in for my website through Facebook. It works this way:

- User goes to my website and chooses to sign in with Facebook
- Users goes to Facebook to authorize my app
- If the app is authorized, the user comes back to my website and gets registered into my database
- The user remains logged in via a cookie set by my website

I store these pieces of information from Facebook: username, email and ID.

**What should happen if:**

- User logs out from Facebook and is still logged into my website? I still have that cookie and session that lets the user remain online, so even if the user isn't logged on Facebook, my users still can benefit from my website. Is this behavior normal or should it be avoided?
- An user removes my *Facebook App* from his authorized apps list? The user is now part of my database, but the user removed the app from his account. How should I deal with this? How can I check if the App->Website connections are still valid for that user? If an user removed the app from his account, should I also remove him from my database? If yes, again, how do I make that check?

There are quite a few other things that are puzzling me and I think I should dedicate another question to those later on.

I'm using Facebook PHP SDK for all these tasks.

**P.S: I only use Facebook as an authentication method for my website, nothing more.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question here are few things we do for the facebook connect

- If user choose to create an account with the FB connect, we grab the
  details like firstname,lastname, email, fb_userid and then save to
  our database.
- If the same user when comes user has to click on the FB login button and we check in our database if the API return fb_userid is in
  our database and process the login and give access to the user pages.
- So ideally we never store the fb_userid in the cookie and next time if the user comes just do the autologin.
- Now what if user remove the app from FB, since we do not allow auto login by cookie saved data the user must click on the login button and then re-authorized the app. Since the fb_userid is already in our db, we detect the user after giving permission and let them login.

  - We have one advantage in our case , i.e. our web app requires monthly subscription so user has to pay for that. So usually people who do want to continue they come to our web site and cancel the account, we then remove the user info and that way fb_userid is also removed at our end. This makes us not to worry what if user remove the app from their FB, since if someone has to cancel they will do it from our website since they are in monthly recurrent billing.
  - I suppose in your case its not as above point, so you can do the following without violating any terms and conditions

    - Do not store the session in cookie and make user login with FB button
      each time they come to your website. Also make a small note on your
      website next to FB login button as "what is this ?" as may be a tool
      tip and mention that the website will store the users fb_userid and
      this will not be shared with any 3rd party.
    - Also mention that in case they remove the app from their facebook the id will be    still there in our database and create
      a cancel account page where user can cancel the account, but that
      needs the user to be logged in. Once they cancel the account remove
      the FB id from your DB.
  - Finally I dont think any API call could be used to see if the user has removed the app for offline users, but people who have logged to your site using the FB connect different permissions could be checked as

  $permissions = $facebook->api( "/me/permissions" );

Comment: Thank you. Just a little thing here though: I'm not storing the FB user ID in the cookie. The cookie has very complex contents which take care of decrypting when being checked to validate an user's authenticity. I use the exact same cookie method for my normal log in process to keep an user logged in if they want to do so. I guess I'm gonna have to update my Privacy Policy.

Comment: Yes, thats the best thing to do let user know via tha Privacy Policy so that its clear to them.

Answer (score 0):

If the app requires Facebook, then you need to test the cases you mention and generate appropriate error messages.  Beyond that, you just provide obvious ways for your user to clean up, like a working uninstall command.